# Can't read Bolt CMS sitemap.xml on nginx

Tags: nginx, bolt-cms

I have a Bolt site with the sitemap extension installed. Going to `example.com/sitemap` produces the expected output, but going to `example.com/sitemap.xml` returns a `403` from nginx. I have a feeling that something isn't quite right with my nginx server block, but I'm not sure what. I do know that I used to receive the same error on PDF files until I explicitly added `pdf` to the "enforce caching" section.

How can I get to the Bolt route /sitemap.xml without nginx first deciding it's a bogus request?

My server config file is below. Names have been changed to protect the innocent.

```
server {
   listen         80;
   server_name    example.com *.example.com;
   return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen         443 ssl;
    server_name    example.com *.example.com;

    ssl_certificate      /home/example/keys/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/example/keys/example.key;

    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file=/srv/http/xhgui.example.com/external/header.php";
    }



root /srv/http/example/web;

index index.php;

# The main Bolt website
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

# Generated thumbnail images
location ~* /thumbs/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

# Bolt backend access
#
# NOTE: If you set a custom branding path, you will need to change '/bolt/' 
#       here to match
location ~* /admin/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

# Enforce caching for certain file extension types
location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|pdf|png|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, mustrevalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}

# Don't create logs for favicon.ico or robots.txt requests
location = /(?:favicon.ico|robots.txt) {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

# Block PHP files from being run in upload (files), app, theme and extension directories
location ~* /(?:app|extensions|files|theme)/(.*)\.php$ {
    deny all;
}

# Block hidden files
location ~ \. {
    deny all;
}

# Block access to Sqlite database files
location ~ \.(?:db)$ {
    deny all;
}

# Block access to the app, cache & vendor directories
location ~ /(?:app|src|tests|vendor) {
    deny all;
}

# Block access to Markdown, Twig & YAML files directly
location ~* /(.*)\.(?:markdown|md|twig|yaml|yml)$ {
    deny all;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my surprise, the block

```
# Block hidden files
location ~ \. {
    deny all;
}
```

appears to apply to *everything*, not just files beginning with a dot. Fixed by changing it to

```
# Block hidden files
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}
```